# Display graphic according to selected input

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I want to display a graphic in another tab according to selected input in the first tab.

For "auto", i want to display a graphic (named "graph_auto") in TAB B and if "boat" is selected, i want to display another graphic (named "graph_boat") in TAB B.This i what i did :

````
---
title: "my report"

output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    social: menu

runtime: shiny
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(flextable)
library(plotly)


```


RESULTS
=======================================================================


Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### TAB A

```{r}
# creation du tibble sur ce KPI

my_data = data.frame(product = rep(c("auto", "boat"),each=2),
                     year = c("2009", "2011", "2005", "2019"),
                     price = c("10 000", "20 000", "7 000", "60 000"),
                     speed = c("220", "250", "70", "140"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("product", "", choices = my_data$product),
  uiOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- renderUI( {
    out <- subset(my_data, product ==input$product)
    library(flextable)
    htmltools_value((flextable(out)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


```


Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### TAB B
```{r}
# if "auto" is selected, then display this graphic
graph_auto <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")

# if "boat" is selected, then display this graphic
graph_boat <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, type = "box", width = 600, height = 400)



```
````

but i am stuck to display graphic according to the selected product. How can we access to selected input from another tab ? Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Pictures of data layouts are not considered [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind (note that the first plot doesn't work)?

````
---
title: "my report"

output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    social: menu

runtime: shiny
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(htmltools)
library(flextable)
library(plotly)



my_data = data.frame(product = rep(c("auto", "boat"),each=2),
                     year = c("2009", "2011", "2005", "2019"),
                     price = c("10 000", "20 000", "7 000", "60 000"),
                     speed = c("220", "250", "70", "140"))
```


RESULTS
=======================================================================


Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### TAB A

```{r}
selectInput("product", "", choices = my_data$product)

renderUI({
  out <- subset(my_data, product ==input$product)
  htmltools_value((flextable(out)))
})
```


Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### TAB B
```{r}
# if "auto" is selected, then display this graphic
renderPlotly({
  if (input$product == "auto") {
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
  }
  # if "boat" is selected, then display this graphic
  if (input$product == "boat") {
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, type = "box", width = 600, height = 400)
  }
})
```
````

You don't need to actually include the structure of a shiny app in `flexdashboard` but only individual UI/`render` elements. Have a look at [the help page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html).